# Creating a PDF with css and html with pandoc

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pandoc, weasyprint

I'm trying to convert HTML+CSS to PDF using pandoc with weasyprint as the pdf engine. I'm using the arguments below but most of the css doesn't get applied.

```
pandoc example.html -t html5 -o example.pdf --pdf-engine weasyprint -c pathtocss.css --standalone
```

Without specifying -c, there is absolutely no styling present in the pdf. After specifying -c, the background color as well as the font colors change, but everything else stays the same.

I've also tried using wkhtmltopdf on its own - not as a pdf-engine - and it worked better, but since wkhtmltopdf doesn't support flex, not all of my styles got applied. Using wkhtmltopdf as the pdf-engine, the result is very similar to using weasyprint, most styles don't get applied.

Edit: I've noticed the CSS that was inside the HTML wasn't getting used at all so I created a second css file with those styles and rerun the command. This time the background images and page numbers work OK, but spacing, tables and lists still look like there is no CSS.

Comment: Maybe weasyprint just doesn't support the CSS you've written? see https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features.html#css To debug, you can also do `pandoc --standalone -o output.html` and then `weasyprint output.html`

Comment: It does. Using weasyprint from python works just fine, prints everything with CSS styles.